# How can I create a container with a curved outside border in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm working on a Flutter project and need assistance with creating a container that has a curved outside border. I've attached a screenshot for reference [image]

I have already attempted a few approaches, such as using the 'BorderRadius' class, but I haven't been able to achieve the desired result. I would greatly appreciate any suggestions, code samples, or guidance on how to create a container with a curved outside border in Flutter. Thank you in advance for your assistance!

Here is my current code for this specific widget

```
Align(
            alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
            child: ClipRRect(
              borderRadius: const BorderRadius.only(
                topLeft: Radius.circular(15),
                bottomLeft: Radius.circular(15),
              ),
              child: BackdropFilter(
                filter: ImageFilter.blur(
                  sigmaX: 5.0,
                  sigmaY: 5.0,
                ),
                child: Container(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 8, horizontal: 5),
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(color: ColorConstants.white.withOpacity(0.2)),
                  child: Row(
                    mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                    children: [
                      Container(
                        height: 30,
                        width: 4,
                        margin: const EdgeInsets.all(4),
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          color: ColorConstants.white.withOpacity(0.6),
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
                        ),
                      ),
                      Column(
                        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                        children: [
                          _likeButton(),
                          _buttons(AssetsConstants.chat),
                          _buttons(AssetsConstants.more),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          )
```

Comment: You can create a custom ShapeBorder for this ,  `Container(shape: CustomShapeBorder())`

Comment: my Bad, I was talking about `Container(decoration: ShapeDecoration( shape: CustomShapeBorder()))`

Answer (score 1):

You need to understand [CipPath](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/ClipPath-class.html) and [Path](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-ui/Path-class.html) and concepts like coordinate system, for shapes that are little or more complex.
Drawing shapes is little complex initially. But once you get the hang of it, there are many benefits like most languages have common pattern and similar code, etc.

I have created a demo app for you with your requirements.
You need to play around with it.

[image]

Here is the code. Replace new flutter main.dart file code with the following code.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        colorScheme: ColorScheme.fromSeed(seedColor: Colors.deepPurple),
        useMaterial3: true,
      ),
      home: const MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class CustomContainer extends CustomClipper<Path> {
  @override
  Path getClip(Size size) {
    var path = Path();
    path.moveTo(size.width, 0);
    path.quadraticBezierTo(
      size.width,
      32,
      size.width - 32,
      32,
    );
    var leftMaxPos = size.width * 0.70;
    path.lineTo(leftMaxPos + 32, 32);
    path.quadraticBezierTo(
      leftMaxPos - 32,
      32,
      leftMaxPos - 32,
      96,
    );
    path.lineTo(leftMaxPos - 32, size.height - 96);
    path.quadraticBezierTo(
      leftMaxPos - 32,
      size.height - 32,
      leftMaxPos + 32,
      size.height - 32,
    );
    path.lineTo(size.width - 32, size.height - 32);
    path.quadraticBezierTo(
      size.width,
      size.height - 32,
      size.width,
      size.height,
    );
    path.close();
    return path;
  }

  @override
  bool shouldReclip(covariant CustomClipper<Path> oldClipper) {
    return false;
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({super.key, required this.title});

  final String title;

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Theme
            .of(context)
            .colorScheme
            .inversePrimary,
        // Here we take the value from the MyHomePage object that was created by
        // the App.build method, and use it to set our appbar title.
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Container(
        color: Colors.brown,
        height: MediaQuery
            .of(context)
            .size
            .height,
        width: MediaQuery
            .of(context)
            .size
            .width,
        child: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.end,
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
          children: [
            ClipPath(
              clipper: CustomContainer(),
              child: Container(
                height: MediaQuery
                    .of(context)
                    .size
                    .height * 0.60,
                width: MediaQuery
                    .of(context)
                    .size
                    .width * 0.60,
                decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                  color: Color(0xC0FFFFFF),
                ),
                child: Column(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.end,
                  mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
                  children: [
                    IconButton(
                      icon: const Icon(
                        Icons.thumb_up,
                        color: Colors.white,
                        size: 50,
                      ),
                      onPressed: () {},
                    ),
                    IconButton(
                      icon: const Icon(
                        Icons.maps_ugc,
                        color: Colors.white,
                        size: 50,
                      ),
                      onPressed: () {},
                    ),
                    IconButton(
                      icon: const Icon(
                          Icons.more_horiz,
                        color: Colors.white,
                        size: 50,
                      ),
                      onPressed: () {},
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

The easiest way is to use `CustomPainter`.[Documentations](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/CustomPaint-class.html)

You can use this [website](https://shapemaker.web.app/#/) to generate the widget.

Here is a simple solution I made using that website.
[image]

***Custom Painter Code***

```
class CustomPainterBorder extends CustomPainter{
  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
  Paint paint0 = Paint()
      ..color = const Color.fromARGB(199, 81, 0, 255)
      ..style = PaintingStyle.fill
      ..strokeWidth = 1;    
    Path path0 = Path();
    path0.moveTo(size.width*0.2086333,size.height*0.2810143);  path0.cubicTo(size.width*0.2086583,size.height*0.3694286,size.width*0.2079083,size.height*0.4475143,size.width*0.2081667,size.height*0.5077143);    path0.cubicTo(size.width*0.2181667,size.height*0.5638429,size.width*0.2801667,size.height*0.4989286,size.width*0.2916667,size.height*0.5615714); path0.quadraticBezierTo(size.width*0.2918167,size.height*0.5466000,size.width*0.2922500,size.height*0.5030000);
    path0.lineTo(size.width*0.2907500,size.height*0.2787143);
path0.quadraticBezierTo(size.width*0.2908167,size.height*0.2373571,size.width*0.2908333,size.height*0.2244286);  path0.cubicTo(size.width*0.2807833,size.height*0.2922429,size.width*0.2061417,size.height*0.2395286,size.width*0.2086333,size.height*0.2810143);
    path0.close();
    canvas.drawPath(path0, paint0);
  }
  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(covariant CustomPainter oldDelegate) {
    return false; // if you want to animate return true 
  }
  
}
```

**Widget code**

```
child: CustomPaint(
  size: Size(100, 400), // Size([width],[height])
  painter: CustomPainterBorder(),
),
```